# SharePoint List Button that browses for files and folders, then puts path and file names in SharePoint List Column WITHOUT using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a button using SharePoint designer that onclick will allow users to browse folders and then put the contents (`path:\filenames`) into a sharepoint list column. I have used the below code and it works except I need a solution that does NOT use activeX as my system is set to not allow unsigned activex.  I am open to any solution that will work on a sharepoint list that does not use and activex control. My button `onclick="getFolderFiles()"`

```
function getFolderFilesSub(fsoFolder, astrFolderFiles) {
    var eFiles = new Enumerator(fsoFolder.Files);
    eFiles.moveFirst();
    While (eFiles.atEnd() ==false) {
       astrFolderFiles.push(eFiles.item().Path);
       eFiles.move.next();
    }

    var eSubFolders = new Enumerator(fsoFolder.SubFolders);
    eSubFolders.moveFirst();
    while (eSubFolders.atEnd() == false({
        getFolderFilesSub(eSubFolders.item(), astrFolderFiles);
         eSubFolders.moveNext();
    }
}

function getFolderFiles() {
    var objShell = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application');
    var objShellFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, 'Choose a folder', 0, 0);

    if (objeShellFolder != null) {

        var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
        var fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(objShellFolder.Items().Item().Path);

        astrFolderFiles = new Array();

        getFolderFilesSub(fsoFolder, astrFolderFiles);

        if (astrFolderFiles.length != 0) {
            var strFolderFiles = astrFolderFiles[0];
            for (var i=1; i <= astrFolderFiles.length-1; i++) {
                strFolderFiles = (strFolderFiles + '\n\ + astrFolderFiles[i];
            }
            document.getElementById(ct100$PlaceHolderMain$g_85cf34cd_8dc3_47ca_85d9_
                                    a6f47297db56$ffFileNames$ct100#ct100$text
                                    field").value = strFolderFiles;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've improved the formating for you on your code as best I could, you'll notice near the end there appears to be some syntax errors, you should fix those

Comment: Thanks Jared. Any idea how to do the above without using ActiveX?